# SailsJS reverse destruction of created models fails

Tags: sails.js

Suppose I have 2 models (one-to-many); Center model (one) - Room model (many).

When creating a center, an array of rooms is created in the Center.Create callback.
If a room creation fails, it should destroy all the created data before the failed room entity.

CenterController create:

```
create: function(req, res) {

    console.log('params: ', req.params.all());
    var centerObj = {
        name: req.param('center_name'),
        state: req.param('center_state')
    };
    var roomsInput = req.params('rooms');

    console.log('created center centerObj: ', centerObj);
    Center.create(centerObj, function centerCreated(err, center) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            req.session.flash = {
                err: err
            }

            console.log("Error in center create")
            return res.redirect('/center/new');
        }

        // keep track of successfully created rooms
        var created_rooms_ids = new Array();
        async.mapSeries(

            // array to iterate over
            roomsInput,

            // iterator function
            function(roomInput, cb)
            {
                var roomObj = {
                    name: roomInput.name,
                    center: center.id,
                    min_age: roomInput.min_age,
                    max_age: roomInput.max_age
                };

                Room.create(roomObj, function roomCreated(err, room) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Room.create error: ", err);
                        return cb(err);
                    }
                    created_rooms_ids.push(room.id);
                    return cb(null, room.id);
                });
            },

            // callback for when the loop is finished
            function(err, results)
            {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error');
                    return destroyCreatedResources(err);
                }
                console.log('center: ', center);
                return res.redirect('/center/show/' + center.id);

                // destroy created resources (center + room)
                function destroyCreatedResources(err)
                {
                    console.log("destroyCreatedResources. Center=", center.id, "Id=", created_rooms_ids);
                    Center.destroy({id: center.id}).exec(function(e){
                        Room.destroy({id: created_rooms_ids}).exec(function(e){
                            console.log('Room.destroy');
                            if (e) {console.log('Room.destroy error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');}
                            return res.serverError(err);
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    });
},
```

**Problem**

When an error happens in the middle and I want to perform reverse destruction of all the created rooms, **only the center is destroyed**.
How come res.serverError(err); is called before the Rooms are destroyed?

```
                function destroyCreatedResources(err)
                {
                    Center.destroy({id: center.id}).exec(function(e){
                            console.log('Room.destroy');
                            if (e) {console.log('Room.destroy error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');}
                        Room.destroy({id: created_rooms_ids}).exec(function(e){
                            return res.serverError(err);
                        });
                    });
                }
```

**Are there better ways to do reverse destruction?**

Comment: Have you verified that 1) `created_rooms_ids` contains the data you expect, and 2) `Room.destroy` isn't throwing an error of its own?

Comment: yes. I modified the function (see the new edit).
destroyCreatedResources. Center= 534719b3161de31c1f67d0e8 Id= [ '534719b3161de31c1f67d0e9', '534719b3161de31c1f67d0ea' ]
Room.destroy
error: Server Error (500)
error:

Comment: Ok, just to be clear--can you put a log inside the callback for `Room.destroy` and see if it's throwing an error?  Like `console.log('Room Destroy Error: ', e);`.  You already know that `Center.destroy` is working, so a log isn't necessary there.

Comment: the output is: Room Destroy Error: ', null

Comment: in sails 0.9 it used to work. the problem here is passing array of ids, Room.destroy({id: created_rooms_ids}), if i pass a single element then it works: Room.destroy({id: created_rooms_ids[0]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was due to a bug in `sails-mongo v0.10.0-rc2`.  This has now been [patched](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/commit/940aed4e812aeb81ea7586c5294e62e3840f77ba) and released as v0.10.0-rc3, so you can pull down the latest from npm and the issue should be resolved.  Thanks!